# How to use slice in forloop django?

Tags: python, django

right now I am trying to use slice in my template but it is showing the this error:-
`TemplateSyntaxError at /post/`

`'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for item in user_basic_info |slice:"2"`

what I am doing is:

```
{%for item in user_basic_info |slice:"2"%}
                        <li>
                            <div class="userimg_sec">
                                <div class="userimg">
                                    <img src="{{ item.profileImage }}">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="userdetails">
                                <p class="username">{{ item.name }}</p>
                                <p class="usernickname">@{{ item.username }}, <span>teacher</span></p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: you can not do it like this if you want to use slice you have to use it on item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the space:

```
{% for item in user_basic_info|slice:"2" %}
           <!-- remove space ^^-->
```

Answer (score 2):

asper the doc you need use like that

```
{% for item in user_basic_info|slice:":2" %}
```

if you want know more refer the docs [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)